# reorder two byte hexadecimal in python

Tags: python, hex, decimal

I need a fast and efficient approach.

```
0x11 and 0xc  ->  0x0c11
0x16 and 0x44 -> 0x4416
```

I currently do it like this hacky way which i think i causing my slow down

```
hexs = str('0x' + format(second, '02x')) + str(format(first, '02x'))
return int(hexs, 0)
```

I see other examples that are kind of similar but they seem to not add in the first 0 in the first example.  It needs to be 2 bytes.

[Python - Decimal to Hex, Reverse byte order, Hex to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995812/python-decimal-to-hex-reverse-byte-order-hex-to-decimal) is one example that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why not just `second << 8 | first`

Comment: Using ordinary bit-shifting arithmetic is probably going to be faster than any approach that converts the numbers to strings, combines them, and converts them back to integers.

Comment: You know that simple solution did it.  I guess I need to look into register shifts a little more.  Thanks @SamiKuhmonen