# Reverse int as hex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have int in python that I want to reverse

`x = int(1234567899)`
I want to result will be `3674379849`

explain : = `1234567899` = `0x499602DB` and `3674379849` = `0xDB029649`

How to do that in python ?

Comment: convert int to hex-string (hint: python has built-in function `hex`), reverse string, convert string to int again.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to convert from little-endian to big-endian representation vice versa. Am I correct?

Comment: In that case, you probably want struct.pack and struct.unpack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Decimal to Hex, Reverse byte order, Hex to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995812/python-decimal-to-hex-reverse-byte-order-hex-to-decimal)

Comment: I don't understand the question. If I need to read potential answers to guess the actual question, I feel there need more details / explanations in the question itself.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('>I', struct.pack('<I', 1234567899))[0]
3674379849
>>>
```

This converts the integer to a 4-byte array (`I`), then decodes it in reverse order (`>` vs `<`).

Documentation: [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the result, use [sabiks  approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63610471/7505395)  - if you want the intermediate steps for bragging rights, you would need to

- create the hex of the number (#1) and maybe add a leading 0 for correctness
- reverse it 2-byte-wise (#2)
- create an integer again (#3)

f.e. like so

```
n = 1234567899
# 1
h = hex(n)              
if len(h) % 2:    # fix for uneven lengthy inputs (f.e. n = int("234",16))
    h = '0x0'+h[2:]
# 2 (skips 0x and prepends 0x for looks only)
bh = '0x'+''.join([h[i: i+2] for i in range(2, len(h), 2)][::-1])
# 3
b = int(bh, 16)
print(n, h, bh, b)
```

to get

```
1234567899 0x499602db 0xdb029649 3674379849
```