# Fastest way to swap bytes of big file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a project I need to swap 4 byte words in a fast way. I need to switch every word(4Bytes) of a big file(2mb) before I can use a other calculation algorithm.

```
def word_swaper(data):
    buf_swaped_data = b""

    number_of_words = int(len(data) / 4)

    for word in range(number_of_words):
        newword = data[word*4:(word+1)*4]
        newword = newword[::-1]
        buf_swaped_data += newword
```

Is there a faster or more simpler way? I'm going to use this for files with a size about 2mb and so the calculating time is about 1-2 minutes, which is way to long.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63610471/683329
Probably you could modify it to do it in batches, or even all at once...

Comment: I also recommend you to use multiprocessing if you have a processor with multiple cores, this will allow you to split your file as much as the cores amount you want to use and execute your code on a file section on each core

Comment: If you want to do it the fastest as you can, and if you have a GPU i also recommend you to check the cudatoolkit library allowing you to execute your code on the GPU. It will be a lot faster

Comment: thank you for your help, at the moment the solution from AKX makes the progress fast enough, but i will keep your idea of multiprocessing in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Using two `io.BytesIO()`s benchmarks to be more than 3x as fast on my box</del> but [there's a built-in method for this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/array.html#array.array.byteswap) that's 550 times faster...

```
import timeit
import os
import io
import array


def original(data):
    buf_swaped_data = b""

    number_of_words = int(len(data) / 4)

    for word in range(number_of_words):
        newword = data[word * 4 : (word + 1) * 4]
        newword = newword[::-1]
        buf_swaped_data += newword
    return buf_swaped_data


def io_pair(data):
    in_io = io.BytesIO(data)
    out_io = io.BytesIO()
    while True:
        word = in_io.read(4)
        if not word:
            break
        out_io.write(word[::-1])
    return out_io.getvalue()


def array_swap(data):
    arr = array.array("L", data)
    arr.byteswap()
    return bytes(arr)


def t(f):
    data = b"1234" * 8000
    assert f(data) == original(data)
    count, time_taken = timeit.Timer(lambda: f(data)).autorange()
    print(f.__name__, count / time_taken)


t(original)
t(io_pair)
t(array_swap)
```

```
original      186.465
io_pair       568.180
array_swap 102897.423
```

Comment: thank you! this is way faster and should also be fast enough for my project.

Comment: @tryanderror I added another method that's, well, 550 times faster, using the `array.byteswap()` builtin.